# C# Copy Cut in GUI

Tags: c#, windows, copy, paste

So I want to have an Edit bar in my C# Windows Form. Is there any way to easily have a these options added? It just needs to copy text.

Comment: Do you mean a menu option at the top like this: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s4p1.html or something else like a tool bar? Can you be more specific please.

Answer (score 3):

.NET provides you with `MenuStrip` Class. Check this [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menustrip%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
It also has a `Clipboard` Class. [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).
Go through these links and you will get what you need. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use Clipboard class and use SetText() and GetText() methods for copy paste.

```
Clipboard.SetText(MyTextBox.Text);

MyTextBox.Text = Clipboard.GetText();
```

Answer (score 0):

Drag a `ToolStrip` from the toolbox onto your form or control. Click on the top right expand button of the tool strip and select `Insert Standard Items`. Now you have the visual elements you need.

Simply remove all the not needed ones and double click on all you like to use. Within the created click handlers add the desired code by using the [`Clipboard` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.aspx).